# Can a "full-REST-SPA" architecture improve performances and network load over classic/template architecture?

Tags: rest, templates, single-page-application

**QUESTION:**

Could SPA+REST approach really improve the network loading ( and maybe performances ) in both client and server side instead of rendering html via php templates?

**WHAT I'M EXACTLY ASKING ( FOR DUMMIES ) :**

I'm ask if anyone has already built a project with this kind of architecture and if they had issues/improvements about performances.

**THE THREAD:**:

I'm **trying to create a modular and very scalable system** that is composed by a client 
written in html+javascript and different **server applications** , mainly written in php, **that communicate with the client using REST.**

**Also i'm fascinated by the SPA** ( Single Page Application ) concept and this is the way i would create the client that should be a social application with dynamic AJAX contents loaded in runtime.

So, as you can guess,  the idea is to **completely separate the html from php** and keep it as "clean" as possible ( in this way i don't have to care about the server language ).

Somewhere i've read about multiple **advantages of SPA, including the possibility to avoid useless loading of redundant parts of the page**.

**WHY I CANNOT BE MORE SPECIFIC:**

i'm in "brainstorming" phase of a project so i cannot post code or ask something very very specific if i've nothing in my hands actually.

**

### THE FAQ

**

**THE ANSWHERE IS SUBJECTIVE?**

**NO** I'm asking about benchmark / performances statistics ... mathematic

**WHY DON'T YOU TEST BY YOURSELF?**

**Yes i'll do it too** , and i could share my results for the community by an answere as i did before. But maybe someone else has done it better before...

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: you can find in title and in the post...are you familiar with question marks?

Comment: the answer could be subjective, you should do your own research / benchmark in what you would like to do.... a response with a small json performs better then just split a huge amount of html, but what happens the other way around, huge json vrs small html?

Comment: benchmarks are not subjectives...anyway, i'll do some tests that i could post as an accepted answere ( as i did in other questions ) if they were valid enough ...however the post and the title respect the guideline and the quest is well-formulated and well explained.
But i won't answere/contribute to anything else here since the question must be well explained but the downvoting are obscenely free..

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask before posting a question, don't take it personal, it sounds more like “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

Comment: where do you read it?...my question is more like: "has anyone tested an SPA architecture with REST? is faster/lighter than classic one?"

Comment: yes and yes. But the problem is that building something in the "classic" way and then rebuilding it as a SPA just to run some timing tests is not going to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After posting this question on google+ ( without additions "for dummies" ) they understood my request and i've found also a reasonable answer that is not subjective at all ( last comment):**

https://plus.google.com/u/0/104873054042278826576/posts/gAhDryGxE3h

**Note for the community:**

*i know that probably this answer will be moderated/deleted, but i feel compelled to say that the stackoverflow system has become not constructive in any way, starting from the "anonymous" and "explain - less" downvoting system. It allows people that doesn't understand the question , or just don't like it, to freely downvote without any explaination, even if a post can be really useful for other people. Moreover you can't understand you errors (if really any)*

*"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."
it seems instead ( for many people i've heard ) more a massive multiplayer game where if other players love your game style, you won't be banned. i prefere the gameover at this point ;)*